# Leaf count in Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Is there a way to know exactly how many leaves are in a binary search tree? Like is there some formula to always find out? For example, if there were 100 nodes in a BST, can you use that value (n=100) to find out how many leaves there are?

Comment: Hmm.  Good question.  I think it's always n+1 leaves but I'm not certain

Comment: You mean (n/2) + 1? That's my initial guess, but I'm not sure.

Comment: No, but you can say the minimum number is 1 and the maximum number is about n/2 rounded up.

Comment: What is your input information? If it's depth and number of nodes only, and a leaf is defined as having no children, then it's impossible to say how many leaves there are, as you can make one large branch, and fork as many leaves as you want by forking from it (at the expense of height, and up to ~n of course). If you have height it might be possible to draw more conclusions.

Comment: If a leaf is a node without children and if you have a tree that is maximally unbalanced, so that the root has the lowest value and all children descend to the right, you'd have only one leaf, no?

Comment: Oh wait, I was using the wrong definition of leaves.  Nevermind me.  There's n+1 places to attach a leaf to the bottom, always.  @luk32: He said the input is the number of nodes and that's all.

Comment: If you are assuming that every node has exactly 2 children, then number of leaves = (n+1)/2.  Otherwise, I believe you would have to count, since there is no way to tell how the nodes are arranged.  (e.g., they could be all in a line, resulting in only one leaf)

Comment: @MooingDuck Then it is obviously impossible unless there is some other knowledge, e.g: tree is maximally balanced, or unbalanced. But it also counts as "some more input information". If one can alter the structure, it is trivial to change number of leaves preserving number of nodes.

Comment: It seems that without any more information it would be ceil((n+1) / 2). I wrote a short program to test it out and it averages ~30 leaves, but obviously best case and worst case are less likely to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It depends on the type of tree in question.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees)

For any general "Binary Search Tree", with no further clarifications or information, we can't know for sure.

It can be anywhere from

- just a single (1) leaf (in which all nodes except the last have only 1 child node - effectively a linked list)
- to a maximum of [ (n + 1) / 2 ] leaves (in which all nodes, save for the leaves, each have 2 child nodes.)

The type of the tree can define how many leaves it has. For example, above, the latter is the definition of a "full" binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

Let T be a binary tree with n > 0 nodes.

- If T is maximally balanced, then T has ⌈n / 2⌉ = (n + 1) // 2 leaf nodes,
  where // denotes integer division.
- If T is minimally balanced, then T has 1 leaf node.
- If T has m leaves, then 1 ≤ m ≤ ⌈n / 2⌉.